# Name of directory from jar file system differs from regular file system

Tags: java, jar, java-7, nio

**EDIT**: I'm rephrasing my original question (I keep it at the bottom)

Take a look at this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        // file in file system

        Path dir = Paths.get("webapp/");
        System.out.println(dir.getFileName().toString());

        // file in jar

        FileSystem fs =  FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get("ajar.jar"), null);
        Path jarDir = fs.getPath("webapp/");
        System.out.println(jarDir.getFileName().toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

First I'm getting a `Path` from a directory in the file system and I print its name. The output is:

```
webapp
```

Then I open a `FileSystem` from a jar file which contains the same folder and do the same as before. This is the corresponding output:

```
webapp/
```

Is there a reason for getting the trailing '/' in the jar's folder's name?

How do I get just the name of the folder with no slash, without having to differentiate among the two cases (jar and no jar)?

Thanks!

--- original question ---

I'm experimenting a bit with Java SE 7's nio library.

Take a look at this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        // List files in file system

        Path dir = Paths.get("webapp/");

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
            for (Path file : stream) {
                System.out.println(file.toString());
            }
        }

        // List files in jar

        FileSystem fs =  FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get("ajar.jar"), null);
        Path jarDir = fs.getPath("webapp/");

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(jarDir)) {
            for (Path file : stream) {
                System.out.println(file.toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Basically first I'm creating a `DirectoryStream` from a folder in my file system and iterate on the content, the output is something like this:

```
webapp/afile.txt
webapp/afolder
```

Then I open a `FileSystem` from a jar file which contains the same folder and do the same as before. This is the corresponding output:

```
/webapp/afile.txt
/webapp/afolder/
```

Now, this is really driving me crazy... why on earth would the output differ?

I can understand the '/' prefix in the jar's output since the files are in the root relatively to the jar file system (even though I don't think I still accept it), but the '/' suffix after a directory is outrageous!

It sucks that I have to write different code to handle the two cases... Of course, here I'm exaggerating on the problem and I know it's easily fixed... but still... why??

Thanks folks!

Comment: Is there actually a functional difference in how you interact with the `Path` other than the output of `toString`?

Comment: @BrettOkken so far, I didn't find functional differences...

Comment: So what different code do you have to write?

Comment: For instance, I want to have a set with the folders' names contained both in the jar and in the file system (i.e. with no repetition if the folders are contained both in the jar and out)... i cannot add the names in the set just calling toSting cause they will be different...

Comment: Why not use `Files.isDirectory` to determine if a `Path` is a directory? The `Path.toString` does not make any guarantees about the representation other than the separator character used.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)

Comment: as I said in the question, I know you can easily overcome the "problem" in many ways... I'm just wandering if there is a reason for it to be like this, or it's just a different implementation that, in spite of being completely legit, is designed to drive people like me (read: OCD oriented :D) crazy...

Comment: The reason for the difference of the leading / is because children of a relative dir are relative, i.e. without the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of a all the comments:

- Don't rely on the string version a Paths. Use the paths directly.
- To differentiate dirs form files use Files.isDirectory on the path
- relative dirs have relative childs

i.e. you should be able to write code to handle both cases. This is whats nio is for.

Answer to the modified question:

The filename of a path p: p.getFileName().

The string representation of the filename of p: p.getFileName().toString().

This string has no slashes.
e.g. 
fs.getPath( "abc", "def" ).getFileName().toString() -> "def"

Comment: Of course i wouldn't rely on a toString for functional purpose... I don't get your "relative dirs have relative childs"... both "webapp/afolder" and "webapp/afolder/" are relative, aren't they?

Comment: @jamp yes, but /webapp/afolder is absolute. The directory stream of a absolute path produces absolute child path. The stream of a relative path produces relative paths.

Comment: Does this should explain the trailing '/'? That has nothing to do with absolute or relative... am I missing your point?

Comment: @jamp No it does not explain the trailing '/'. The reason for it is, as Brett Okken wrote, that toString is not specified precisely and is implemented differently in different filesystem.